# Is it possible to query non distinct values?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: table1 contains field called `domain names` and another field called `keyvalues`.

What I need to do is to query all domain names where the key value is not distinct. (I know about group by, but group by will not retrieve the non distinct domain names). I need to do this because I want to delete them after querying them.

Comment: can you provide a model of the table? is very difficult understand your question on that way.

Comment: Typed out a Query response and then realized that this is mySQL, not SQL. Basically you want to get group count and delete any record where count > 1

Answer (score 4):

```
select domainnames
from your_table
group by domainnames
having count(distinct keyvalues) <> count(keyvalues)
```

Comment: You beat me. I wrote the same query, but you posted faster. :)